# Tensorflow: CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES doesn't seem to work

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, gpu

When I run my python script with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`, Tensorflow still shows the following:

> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id:
>   0000:86:00.0)

Consequently, my code fails with the following message:

> Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:2'
>   because no devices matching that specification are registered in this
>   process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0,
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0

Could someone please explain what must be going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Citing the explanation of [CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES](http://www.acceleware.com/blog/cudavisibledevices-masking-gpus):

> CUDA will enumerate the visible devices starting at zero. In the last
>   case, devices 0, 2, 3 will appear as devices 0, 1, 2.

So if you do `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`, then your gpu #2 will be denoted as `gpu:0` inside tensorflow.

Comment: In my case, I track the pciBusID and it allocates the same GPU no matter what I specify as argument of CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES. Running on Ubuntu 16.04 with 4 GPUs.